# Skelet Theorie, can anyone help?

Tags: aerodynamics, compressed-gases

I am studying Gas dynamics and came across the lift angle approximation as based on Skelett Theorie (in german). I have done google searches on finding this theory but no luck on any information. Can anyone perhaps in Aerodynamics help? Thanks.

Comment: So try a library perhaps that theory has not made it to Google, but is in a paper or journal...